# “Why would you” VS “why will you”

Tags: grammar, word-usage

1. Why would you do that?
2. Why will you do that?

What are the difference between 1 and 2? I watched a movie and an enemy offered to help the male lead, and the male lead said “why would you do that?”.

I was wondering why he used “would” instead of “will”. I know the difference between “would” and “did”, but does the difference also apply to “would” and “will”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both questions ask for an explanation of an action. "Why would you do that?" implies that the action is a possibility, but it may not happen. "Why will you do that?" implies that the action is definitely going to happen. In this case, would is a better word choice since the help being given is only a hypothetical, it might or might not happen.

Comment: More info here: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would